# Disable Anchor tag and remove underline also in javascript

Tags: javascript, anchor, href

I have a anchor tag which I would like to disable or enable depending upon some condition. I am able to achive this using the following function:

```
function disableEnableAnchor(obj, disable) {
    if(disable) {
        var href = obj.getAttribute("href");
        if(href && href != "" && href != null)
            obj.setAttribute('href_bak', href);
        obj.removeAttribute('href');        
    } else {
        var href_bak = obj.attributes['href_bak'].nodeValue;        
        obj.setAttribute('href', href_bak);
    }
}
```

But I am not able to remove the underline when the anchor is in a disabled state. How can I achieve this inside this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a stylesheet issue. Is there something like

```
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

in a CSS file that’s applied to the page?

Replacing it with the following CSS should make `<a>` tags only be underlined when they have an `href` attribute.

```
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
obj.style.textDecoration = "none"
```

Comment: this wouldn't work as it would make the obj lose its already set text decoration like disabled and greying out.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider replacing the anchor with a span.

Comment: What I want is that once the anchor is disabled i.e it doesnt contain 'href' attribute and attribute 'disabled' is true , the underline should not appear. how should I go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this on HTML:

```
<a href="mylink" style="text-decoration
```